# SpringBoot : How ReflectionTestUtils.setFields work?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit

Consider the below code:

**Service**

```
class MyService{

  @Autowired
  private ModelMapper modelMapper;


  void validate(){

       ResponseObject obj = modelMapper.map( REQUEST, ResponseObject.class);
 
       // In testing, if I am not mocking this Model Mapper, an exception will be thrown.

  }

}
```

**Testing**

Here in JUnit test cases, instead of mocking, I am making use of **ReflectionTestUtils.setField("", "", "")** and the mapping takes place as expected. But I am not aware of what's happening and how it's working. I referred to many sources, but I couldn't find any reliable resource regarding this. ***Can someone tell me whats ReflectionTestUtils, how its works, and when to use it?***

```
@InjectMocks
MyService service;

private ModelMapper modelMapper;

@BeforeEach
void setup() {
    modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField( service, "modelMapper", modelMapper);

}
```

Comment: The `setField` set the field `"modelMapper"` on the target `service` to the value of the third parameter (`modelMapper`). The first argument is the target object, the second is the field name and the third is the value to set. It's someway similar to a injection.

Comment: You can view [the source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.java#L175) for it. Short answer, reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses reflection API under the cover to set the value for an object 's field.

About when to use it , the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#unit-testing-utilities) already provides some info :

> You can use these methods in testing scenarios where you need to
> change the value of a constant, set a non-public field, invoke a
> non-public setter method, or invoke a non-public configuration or
> lifecycle callback method when testing application code for use cases
> such as the following:
>
> - ORM frameworks (such as JPA and Hibernate) that condone private or
>   protected field access as opposed to public setter methods for
>   properties in a domain entity.
> - Spring’s support for annotations (such as @Autowired, @Inject, and
>   @Resource), that provide dependency injection for private or protected
>   fields, setter methods, and configuration methods.
> - Use of annotations such as @PostConstruct and @PreDestroy for
>   lifecycle callback methods.

I normally use it for setting up some dummy domain objects which are JPA entities for testing. Since their ID are managed by Hibernate and to have a good encapsulation , they do not have any setter or constructor to configure their ID value , and hence need to use it to setup some dummy values for their ID.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing the *very* anti-pattern (if you ask me) :

```
@Autowired
private ModelMapper modelMapper;
```

you can always inject it via the constructor:

```
private final ModelMapper modelMapper;

class MyService(ModelMapper modelMapper) {
    this.modelMapper = modelMapper;
}
```

when `MyService` is a bean that spring is aware of, the auto-wiring will happen for you. So no need to use the `ReflectionTestUtils.setField`; which will start failing in `jdk-17` and up.

---

Since you now pass it via a constructor, injection with a mock for example, is trivial.